# "Select next row" and "Updated value on" in Loadrunner parameterization

Tags: loadrunner

I am running single script with 2 virtual users and I have 10 unique data in parameter file in that file repeated data can't be used, each time user should take data uniquely.

I have selected options in parameter file Select next row as "Unique" and Updated value on "Once" , My logic is not working.

Please help me out, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please re-read the section of your training material associated with parameterization or the manual on same.  Once means just that, update this record once and hold this value forever.   As you have ten records and two virtual users and ten records the natural breakout is unique with a block size of five and exit after data is exhausted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir ,Can u please elaborate bit about this answer?

Comment: The above should make full sense once you have taken advantage of the online versions of the manuals or reviewed the HP standard course curriculum material associated with parameterization.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Parameters' Run-Time settings, making the 'select next row' option 'Unique' effectively divides the available rows of data for that parameter evenly between the number of vusers you set in the test scenario. In this example 5 rows of data will be available to one vuser and the other 5 rows available to the second vuser. You can also manually allocate a certain number of rows to each vuser if you wish. This allows you to ensure each of the virtual users don't use the same rows of data.

Setting the 'update value' setting to 'Once' means a parameter's value will be populated only one time during the test run, the first time the parameter is called in your script. The default script behavior is to grab a new value each iteration, so this setting changes that.

Based on what you describe here you have two virtual users and 10 rows of data. Each vuser will pull one unique line of data to populate the parameter and then use that same value for the rest of the test, every iteration.